# As-you-type spell-checking for VS2012

Tags: plugins, razor, visual-studio-2012

After Google I couldn't find As-you-type spell-checking  for VS2012.

I have used one for VS210. I don't remember name of it which was quite useful to avoid spell mistakes in  **Aspx/razor Views**

Does anyone know any free plugin,extension for VS2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [`spell checker`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/04/spell-checker-extension-for-visual-studio-2012-html-asp-net-css-and-other-files.aspx) you might try for VS 2012. You could download it from the [`Visual Studio Extensions Gallery`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09cdc0c3-c50b-4bfd-a567-b7125c244b10).

Comment: This does not have As-you-type spell checking